# How to connect existing hosting account with new domain

Tags: dns, cross-domain, hosting, web-hosting, nameservers

i have bought a domain(adspace.lk) and hosting from the same service provider (lankahost.net). but now my domain has expired and my hosting account is still available with all my files.

now i have bought another domain (.com) at name.com .i want to connect my new domain  name.com to the existing hosting account.

Is there any way to do it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is **NOT** about programming, but about domain management

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sort of, yes. Assuming that the machine you're hostin your files on has an ip address set aside for your exclusive use - that is, not "shared" hosting - you can simply create an A record with the new new, and that ip address. You must also change your webserver config - if you're using any web related stuff - such that the webserver can associate your web site files with the new name. Usually, a web host can have multiple names at the same time, so you could simply add a new name to the existing configuration.

Comment: i have created a A record. but it redirects to `http://isaithuli.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi`. i also read that , it will take 48 hours for the DNS record to be active. do i need to wait or is there is an error with my DNS record..

Comment: the authoritative nameservers should resolve that record much earlier than 48 hours - what they probably mean is that a previous version of that record will be cached elsewhere for some time.  Query one of the authoritative servers directly, to see whether your change had effect. Rest of the world may have to wait for some time, because of those possibly cached records, over which you have no control now.  use dig or drill to query authoritative servers.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer without knowing the details of your domain and hosting settings, but I'll try to give a generic but hopefully useful answer.

You should first get the ip(s) of your hosting. Then point the new domain to that ip(s) using the dns panel provided by the registrar. If you use your own dns (unlikely), set the ip there.

After this, you should configure some rules on your hosting. It's likely that you have to set some sort of virtualhost settings. In particular, you should associate the new domain name to the hosting: probably the hosting service provides you a control panel for this task.

Answer (score 0):

It will be done easily from your `domain control panel`, just update your `dns settings` for your new domain `name.com`. Update your `nameservers` or `A record` to point the hosting account. So that it will be linked with your existing hosting account files.